# Manipulating Date in Excel code

Tags: datetime, vba, excel

A column in an excel worksheet holds the month in this format:

```
Oct_2010
```

What I want to do is, get the last date of that month. What I figured I would do is, read the month in the cell, get the first day of the next month and then subtract one day, so I get the last date of the previous month.

But, how can I get Excel (VBA code) to read Oct_2010 as Oct 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA

```
Function LastDayFromString(sDate As String) As Date

    Dim dtTemp As Date

    If Not sDate Like "???[_]####" Then Err.Raise 9999, , "Invalid date string format"

    dtTemp = DateValue(Replace(sDate, "_", "/"))

    LastDayFromString = DateSerial(Year(dtTemp), Month(dtTemp) + 1, 0)

End Function
```

Used like

```
?lastdayfromstring("Oct_2010")
10/31/2010
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 =DATE(YEAR(REPLACE(A1,4,1,"/")),MONTH(REPLACE(A1,4,1,"/")),0)
```

Where A1=Oct_2010